# how to Grant Permission on a table to a user on the other database in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi I have a table in my schema to be accessed from a user from Another Oracle databse..

I am trying with

```
GRANT all on a.table_name to test@o11db;
```

here a is my Schema and Test is another schema in o11db. But I am not able to get  it right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle article about [Create database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm):
*To access a remote schema object, you must be granted access to the remote object in the remote database.*

That means you need to grant the privileges *locally* (to the database on which they are) to the user *as whom* a user connect via the database link.

So, for example, if the database link was created like so

```
create database link DB_LINK 
connect to TESTUSER 
identified by PASSTHEWORD
using ...
```

[image]

then you have to

```
grant all on a.tablename to TESTUSER;
```